# Unique null index

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE mandantconfigentity
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  currentlegalversionnumber integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 5,
  belongsto_userid character varying(255)
)
```

How can i create a unique index, which ensures, that the table can have only one row where belongsto_userid is null?

This does not work:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_mandantconfig_for_null_belongsto 
    ON mandantconfigentity (1) 
 WHERE (belongsto_userid IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_mandantconfig_for_null_belongsto 
    ON mandantconfigentity ((1)) 
WHERE (belongsto_userid IS NULL);
```

So what it does - it creates a partial index over expression: that has explicitly the fixed value `1` for every row where `belongsto_userid IS NULL`.

> The syntax of the CREATE INDEX command normally requires writing parentheses around index expressions, as shown in the second example. The parentheses can be omitted when the expression is just a function call, as in the first example.

So extra parentheses are required by the syntax.

References:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html

Answer (score 0):

The code to create index needs column name:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_mandantconfig_for_null_belongsto 
    ON mandantconfigentity (id) 
WHERE (belongsto_userid IS NULL);
```

Comment: How would it ensure only one row at most has `belongsto_userid` equal to `NULL`? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3c614/1

Comment: this won't work, it ensures that the id only occours once when the userid is null